# Why in some cases #pragma omp critical directive is inefficient?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I have read that using #pragma omp critical upon one statement like that is inefficient, i do not know why?

```
double area, pi, x;
int i, n;
...
area = 0.0;
#pragma omp parallel for private(x)
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   x = (i+0.5)/n;
#pragma omp critical
   area += 4.0/(1.0 + x*x);
}
pi = area / n;
```

Comment: It's not so much that you have a critical region of just one statement, the problem is that there is almost nothing *outside* that critical region. Using a critical region is find as long as there is *lots* of stuff outside it. Amdahl/Gustafson's law.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A naive compiler/runtime would do at each iteration:

- take a lock
- compute `4.0 / (1.0 + x*x)
- perform `area += ...`
- release the lock

An alternative would be not to use locks, but perform `area += ...` with an atomic instruction.

In both cases, this is way less efficient that using a reduction clause, in which each thread runs without any synchronization, and the reduction (possibly tree-based) only happens at the end of the OpenMP region.

Answer (score 3):

Widening [@Gilles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8062491/gilles-gouaillardet) answer a bit, since the question as asked is more general than the code.

`omp critical` is a directive which enforces serialisation, therefore only a single thread can execute inside the guarded "critical section". Thus if there is contention on the critical section parallelism is reduced and, with it, performance. A slightly pessimistic way to think if this is that time in the critical section should be added to the serial fraction in [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law). (This is pessimistic because the critical section only reduces parallelism when it is a point of contention. If it is small and rare, that is unlikely.)

In your example, there is more work inside the critical section (2 adds, one multiply, one divide) than outside it (2 adds, one divide, one comparison [I've included the loop overhead here!]). Applying Amdahl then suggests that the maximum parallel efficiency would be 50%.

So `critical` is dangerous from a performance point of view, but is essential for avoiding race conditions, and the performance impact may be minimal if the execution time inside the critical section(s) is small compared with other parallel execution time.

As @Gilles says, here you should definitely be using a reduction.

p.s. **Declare your variables in their minimal scope.** (This was in C89, so you can't argue you need backward compatibility!) This makes the code easier to read and often avoids the need for `private(foo)` directives (so makes the code easier to get right too!)